# Custom Taxonomy rewrite rule causes 404 error on page or single post depending on if it's set to "True" or "False"

Tags: permalinks, urls

I've been googling, tinkering around and investigating/testing settings however nothing seems to work so please bear with me on this and please help me if you can. Thanks so much!

I have the custom taxonomy called "location" created via the CPT UI plugin and "Custom Structure" of example.com/%location%/%postname%/ in Settings >> Permalinks.

Below is the code used by CPT UI plugin to register new taxonomy "location".

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_location() {

    /**
     * Taxonomy: Locations.
     */

    $args = array(
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'location', 'with_front' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "location",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
        );
    register_taxonomy( "location", array( "post", "blog" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_location' );
```

So my standard posts have this URL: sitename.com/"location"/"postname"

However when viewing my standard WP PAGES sitename.com/contact, sitename.com/about-us, and all other items under "pages", it returns 404 error.

**Some investigation result:**When I change `"rewrite"` to False, issue is fixed on the standard page, however 404 error is encountered in the post e.g. sitename.com/"location"/"postname". When `"rewrite"` is set back to True, single post is with no error however 404 is encountered in Page.

Has anyone encountered this issue before, or does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Appreciate your help! Much thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ! My site doesn't have a PAGE with url site.com/location or any of the locations listed under taxonomy: location (e.g. california, etc.). Now, I can visit example.com/{location}/{post-slug} without any issues as rewrite rule is tagged as "True", however my Pages - e.g. example.com/page-slug now all have 404 error. Help? Sorry if I have not understood correctly. Thanks so much for this!

Comment: Sorry, please ignore that comment - I thought I've edited it. What I meant is, when you go to `example.com/page-slug`, WordPress sees it as a "location" request - and will try to find a "location" with the slug `page-slug` - because of your custom structure - `example.com/%location%/` - see the `%location%` part.

Comment: And when you disable the taxonomy's URL rewriting, then `example.com/california/post-slug` for example, defaults to a *child* Page request - i.e. WordPress will try to find a Page with the slug `california/post-slug`.

Comment: Wow @SallyCJ much thanks for the explanation it's much clearer now... Is a better way to handle this problem? 

Also I'm just curious, why is it that in Settings > Permalinks I switch instead to %category%/%post-name%, issue does not exist? Will wp not also see it as a "category" request - and will try to find a "category" with the slug page-slug? (i tried and it's ok - no issues at all)  Thanks so much for your help as always! :)

Comment: By the way if I ultimately am unable to solve this, I'm just thinking of using the standard "category" taxonomy as the default for my locations... meaning my san francisco, new york, los angeles taxonomies that are supposed to be a custom "location" taxonomy, I'll just put them in the standard "wp" Category to avoid further issues. And then I'll just create a custom taxonomy for the actual categories I have for my posts since they are of lesser importance which don't need to go into the url slug.. What do you think? your thoughts on this are highly valued.. Much thanks @SallyCJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in my comments, here are the issues with the `/%location%/%postname%/` permalink structure:

1. When the taxonomy's URL rewriting is *enabled*, going to a Page like `example.com/page-slug` would result in a "page not found" error because WordPress sees the request as a "location" request, where in that example, WordPress would try to find a "location" (a term in that taxonomy) where the slug is `page-slug`.
2. When the taxonomy's URL rewriting is *disabled*, going to a Post like `example.com/california/post-slug` would result in the same "page not found" error because WordPress sees the request as a *child* Page request, where WordPress would try to find a Page where the slug is `california/post-slug`.

Now you asked in the comment:

> Also I'm just curious, why is it that in Settings > Permalinks I
>   switch instead to `%category%/%post-name%`, issue does not exist? Will
>   wp not also see it as a "category" request - and will try to find a
>   "category" with the slug `page-slug`?

And the answer is, because WordPress [automatically](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L1827) turns on "verbose page rules" (or technically, sets [`WP_Rewrite::$use_verbose_page_rules`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php#L251) to `true`) if the permalink structure begins with `%category%` (or with a slash — `/%category`).

And what does that mean is, you can make your custom permalink structure works properly just like the `%category/%post-name%` structure, by *enabling the verbose page rules*.

How so?

Because that way, URLs matching a Page request would first be checked if it's actually a Page.

Which means, in your case, `example.com/page-slug` for example would be checked if it is a Page before checking if it's a "location"/term.

And here's how can you enable the verbose page rules:

```php
register_taxonomy( "location", array( "post", "blog" ), $args );
$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->use_verbose_page_rules = true; // add this
```

I.e. Add the second line after calling `register_taxonomy()`.

Or this works, too:

```php
add_action( 'init', function(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules = true;
}, 1 );
```

*Note: Be sure to flush the permalinks (just visit the Permalink Settings page) after you applied the above code changes.*

Comment: OMG @SallyCJ this worked! I used the second code because it's global and I am unable to edit codes by CPT UI plugin. I've been googling around so much for this but I wasn't able to find a solution like this one! I'm sure this will help out many others! Thanks for giving out two solutions too, this will be very helpful as reference in the future :)

Comment: And @SallyCJ thanks for the explanation too, it all makes perfect sense to me now.. :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)